# $f_n \in H(G)$ converges uniformly on every compact subset of $G$ to a function $f$. Prove $f$ is holomorphic on $G$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a connected open set and $f_n$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions on $G$, which converges uniformly on every compact subset of $G$ to a function $f$. Prove $f$ is holomorphic on $G$

I tried to prove $f$ can be expressed a series of power series
$$ f(z)=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f_m(w)}{{(w-z_0)}^{n+1}}dw \ (z-z_0)^n$$
But I need to put the limit to $f_m$ to finish proof. Can I switch the lim and summation here? Why? Thank you!

Comment: How about using Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: seems I get it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Morera theorem to prove it.

Since $f_n\to f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $G$ and $G$ is connected open set, for any $z\in G$ we can find a closed curve $\gamma$ in $G$ containing $z$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly ($\gamma$ is compact). Since $f_n$ are holomorphic in $\gamma$
$$
\oint_\gamma f_n(z)dz=0
$$
And so
$$
0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\oint_\gamma f_n(z)dz=\oint_\gamma\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(z)dz=\oint_\gamma f(z)dz
$$
(limit and integral can be switched for $f_n\to f$ uniformly). By Morera theorem, this means that $f$ is holomorphic in $G$.